# Do I really have to write 8 different SQL queries for this?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm attempting to write ONE query that will do a COUNT on several columns, group them by their respective column.

Here's the query I have right now:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total,
COUNT(q3_pay) as q3_pay_total,
COUNT(q3_holidays) as q3_holidays_total,
COUNT(q3_vacation) as q3_vacation_total,
COUNT(q3_sick) as q3_sick_total,
COUNT(q3_insurance) as q3_insurance_total,
COUNT(q3_retirement) as q3_retirement_total,
COUNT(q3_fsa) as q3_fsa_total
FROM exit_responses
```

I need to find two things:

1. The total number of responses for each column COUNT(column).
2. The total number of response X for each column COUNT(column[x]) <-- example

Is there any way for me to do this without creating a new sql query for each column?

I currently have other queries that do this such as this one:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total, q2 FROM exit_responses
GROUP BY q2
```

Thanks, everyone :).

Comment: This is not very clear - what are you counting against each column? can you give some sample data and expected output?

Comment: is the table exit_responses set up with all those fields?  Can you set it up to have the column name as a field value and then just group by that?  Maybe a UNION query to normalize before counting....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a definition of the table and a few sample rows of data.

Having said this, something like the following should work.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total,
sum(nvl(q3_pay,0)) as q3_pay_total,
sum(nvl(q3_holidays,0)) as q3_holidays_total,
...
FROM exit_responses
```

Not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your data if those are what you want, but two things you can do:

1. GROUP BY all the different columns and then use `COUNT(DISTINCT col)` to get the number of distinct values in that column
2. GROUP BY any suitable column and then `SUM(IF(col = 'xy',1,0))` to count how often the values meet a certain condition

Answer (score 0):

Count() will return the same number for each column. What you need to do is a SUM() for each one. Make sure you change the value for each one to 1, depending on the content. (You can use a case inside the sum to do so)

Comment: COUNT won't count NULL, so if any of the columns are nullable then there's a possibility that the counts will be different.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, please post DDL or table along with some sample rows and the expected output.

Hmm, I don't suppose this is what you want to do?

```
select 'Q3'                   as quarter,
       count(*)               as total,
       count(q3_pay)          as q3_pay_total,
       count(q3_holidays)     as q3_holidays_total,
       count(q3_vacation)     as q3_vacation_total,
       count(q3_sick)         as q3_sick_total,
       count(q3_insurance)    as q3_insurance_total,
       count(q3_retirement)   as q3_retirement_total,
       count(q3_fsa)          as q3_fsa_total
  from exit_responses
union all
select 'Q2'                   as quarter,
       count(*)               as total,
       count(q2_pay)          as q2_pay_total,
       count(q2_holidays)     as q2_holidays_total,
       count(q2_vacation)     as q2_vacation_total,
       count(q2_sick)         as q2_sick_total,
       count(q2_insurance)    as q2_insurance_total,
       count(q2_retirement)   as q2_retirement_total,
       count(q2_fsa)          as q2_fsa_total
  from exit_responses
```